# why Tostring doesnot convert int to string

Tags: vb.net

Consider this code:

```
Dim a As Integer = 4
Dim c As Integer = 3
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString + c)
Console.ReadLine()
```

it should return 43 as a is being converted to string but still return 7

Comment: "it should return" - I think you can safely assums it's behaving as expected: presumably the string is converted back to an integer again.  Try the & operator.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer joe well u r right when both r strings then these can be easily concatenated but i want to know when we apply + within an int and string why doesn't it concatenate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to convert both operands to string, and/or use the string concatenation operator `&`.

As it stands, you are evaluating this expression:

```
"4" + 3
```

and VB decides to convert the first operand to be an integer to match the second operand. VB will only perform string concatenation with `+` if both operands are strings. It prefers arithmetic with `+`.

Some useful links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c5t70w2.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk.aspx

As you can see from these links, the setting of `Option Strict` plays a role. You clearly have it set to `Off` but frankly setting it to `On` would be prudent.

Personally I'd write it like this

```
a.ToString & c.ToString
```

The bottom line is that if you know you want to concatenate strings, it is always clearer to use the dedicated string concatenation operator `&`.

Comment: thanks so u say for concatenation both operand must be string

Comment: but the first link u provided says "The + Operator (Visual Basic) has the primary purpose of adding two numbers. However, it can also concatenate numeric operands with string operands"

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I repeated that in my answer. And by the way, I re-tagged the question since this is not vb6.